# Hacer que dure una ventana popup mas de 10 segundos

Tags: javascript, html

Como dice el título, quisiera que mi popup dure más tiempo, actualmente no dura ni 10 segundos.

Les dejo mi código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!----POPUP ---->
<div id="palet1" style="display:none;">
    <h2 style="line-height: 2px;">titulo</h2>
    <p>bla bla bla</p>
    <div class="close _close" id="close">
        <a href=javascript:; class="btn_close_nuevo btn" onclick="SaveAndHide1(this)">Aceptar</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!---- POP UP---->

<!---- html ---->
<input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" id="A" value="P"> <font color="black" size="1px">Europeo</font> &nbsp
                <input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" id="B" value="P"> <font color="black" size="1px">Americano</font> &nbsp
                <input type="radio" name="tipo-envio" id="C" value="P"> <font color="black" size="1px">Otros</font>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="enviar_add_evento" class="btn btn-primary1 min-wide1" tabindex="13">BUSCAR</a>
<!----- HTML ----->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $( "input" ).on( "click", function() { 
  if($('#A').is(":checked")){
    $('#enviar_add_evento').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('palet1').style.display="block";
    });
  }else if($('#B').is(":checked")){
    $('#enviar_add_evento').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('palet1').style.display="block";
    });
  }else if($('#C').is(":checked")){
    $('#enviar_add_evento').click(function(){
    document.getElementById('palet1').style.display="block";
    });
  }else{
        //* nothing to do
  }
});

/// funcion para cerrar el cuadro del popup
    function SaveAndHide1(star) {
        palet1.style.display = "none";
    }
```

CSS

```
/* alerta palets */
#palet1 {
position: fixed;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px 25px 3px 25px;
    background: white;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 10px;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 358px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#palet1 a {
color:white;
text-decoration: none;
}

#palet1 a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

#palet1 .close {
cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    right: 59px;
    text-align: right;
}
/* alerta palets */
```

Comment: Para entenderte mejor, lo que buscas es que demore en cerrarse en lugar de cerrarse instantaneamente?

Comment: Si. eso mismo, necesito que dure debido a que en mi web, solo funciona como redireccion y lo que necesito es que por lo menos puedan leer un texto de ese popup.

Comment: Si fuese como dices, que cierran al hacer click al costado, cual seria la solucion ? O como hacer un timer para el boton, para que se redireccione a X pagina en X tiempo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que leas la documentación de **[setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)**, es un evento muy sencillo de usar y puedes aplicarlo en un montón de situaciones.

Te dejo un ejemplo para que puedas interpretar su funcionamiento y aplicarlo a tu problema puntual.

```js
  function funcionInstantanea()
  {
    console.log("Listo.");
  }
  function funcionConDemora(){
      
    setTimeout(function(){

        console.log("Listo tras 10 segundos.");

    },10000);
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="funcionInstantanea()">Ejecución Instantánea</button>
<br>
<button onclick="funcionConDemora()">Ejecución con demora</button>
```

Espero que se entienda, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto era lo que buscaba